# Storing multiple inputs from user entry

Tags: python, tkinter

I want know how i can create a notifier that can store more than 1 time and note given by user entry from a little gui. this code is the very basic i am using:

```
from datetime import datetime
from threading import Timer
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import *
from inputer import *


x = datetime.today()
y = x.replace(day=q, hour=w, minute=e, second=0, microsecond=0)

delta_t = y - x

secs = delta_t.seconds+1

def Note():
    # in this function i put the commands to open 
    # a small window with the reminder/note
    print("hello world")
    #...

t = Timer(secs, Note)
t.start()
```

"inputer" is the file taking the user input. if for example i want to get 2 reminders at the same day. how do i code that? because now the variables for day and time are fixed and can not store more info to use at a certain time.

i am very new to coding sorry if this question seems stupid xd 
(using python btw)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After clarifying I think this would be best, you have multiple timestamps you could store in a list or dictionary

List

```
timestamps = []
timestamp_1 = '1h1m1s' # these variables can be assigned with input() as well
timestamp_2 = '2h2m2s'

timestamps.append(timestamp_1)
timestamps.append(timestamp_2)

print(timestamps[0])
print(timestamps[1])
```

> ```
> chrx@chrx:~/python/stackoverflow/9.23$ python3.7 loop.py 
> 1h1m1s
> 2h2m2s
> ```

Dictionary

```
timestamps = {}
timestamp_3 = '3h3m3s'
timestamp_4 = '4h4m4s'

timestamps['ts_3'] = timestamp_3
timestamps['ts_4'] = timestamp_4

print(timestamps['ts_3'])
print(timestamps['ts_4'])
```

> ```
> 3h3m3s
> 4h4m4s
> ```

Comment: the code you wrote uses different variables for the different inputs but the day, hour, minute from my code each have one var assigned. are you suggesting i could i.e. assign > 1 var to day, time, min?   --to clarify my question: i am basically trying to code an alarm clock that can have multiple alarms per day (like a smartphone) in stead of now when i input a timestamp the older gets replaced by it. --thanks for trying to help btw

Comment: How about something like this ? you could store multiple timestamps in one list or one dictionary and then call them as needed, so say you assign `timestamp = 9h8m10s` then you can `append` that to a list `timestamps.append(timestamp` and and it would be in the `list` then you can call however many `timestamps` you want from that list, same with dictionary but it will allow you to label them whatever you want and access them through their key label

Comment: Expanded to show you with some pseudo variables, gotta go check on my nephew hope this helps